# Faithful $S$-Noetherian module

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, noetherian

I found a problem in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312907984_On_Right_S-Noetherian_Rings_and_S-Noetherian_Modules) on Example 2.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, $S$ a multiplicative subset of $R$, and $M$ a nonzero $S$-Noetherian $R$-module. For $R'=R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(M)$, we have that $M$ is a faithful $S$-Noetherian $R'$-module. How to prove that $R'$ is $S$-Noetherian?

Comment: I think [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763433/if-m-is-a-noetherian-r-module-then-r-textannm-is-a-noetherian-ring) could inspire you.

Comment: thank you very much ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*We prove that if $M$ is faithful $R$-module and $M$ is $S$-Noetherian, then $R$ is $S$-Noetherian.*

Fix $s_0\in S$ such that $Ms_0\subseteq N$ for some finitely generated $R$-submodule of $M$. Write 
$$K = \{x\in R\,|\,s_0x=0\}$$
Note that $\mathrm{Ann}_R(N) \subseteq K$. Indeed, if $Nx=0$, then $0 = Ms_0x$ and hence (by the fact that $M$ is faithful) $s_0x = 0$. Thus $x\in K$. Pick generators $n_1,...,n_k$ of $N$ and consider a morphism
$$\phi:R \rightarrow \bigoplus_{i=1}^kn_iR = L$$
given by $R\ni x\mapsto (n_ix)_{1\leq i\leq k}\in \bigoplus_{i=1}^kn_iR$. Clearly $L$ is $S$-Noetherian as a finite direct sum of $S$-Noetherian modules $n_iR\subseteq M$ for $1\leq i\leq k$. Now the kernel of $\phi$ is $\mathrm{Ann}_R(N)$. **This implies that $R/\mathrm{Ann}_R(N) = R/\mathrm{ker}(\phi)$ is $S$-Noetherian** as an $R$-submodule of $S$-Noetherian module $L$.

Now pick any ideal $I\subseteq R$. By bold statement above there exist $s\in S$ and a finitely generated ideal $J$ of $R$ such that 
$$Is\subseteq J+\mathrm{Ann}_R(N)\subseteq J+ K$$
Then 
$$Iss_0 \subseteq Js_0$$
Now $ss_0\in S$ and $Js_0$ is a finitely generated ideal of $R$. Thus $R$ is $S$-Noetherian.

**Remark.**

$K = \mathrm{Ann}_R(s_0)$
where $s_0$ is treated as an element of $R$-module $R$.

Comment: Is $s$ in $Ann_R(N)$ the same as $s \in S$ (there exist $s \in S$....)?  Also, you said that kernel $\phi$ is $Ann_R(N)$, but why in the implication, kernel $\phi$ is $Ann_R(s)$?

Comment: @R Yes it is the same. Because $Ann_R(N) = \{x\in R\,|\,sx=0\} = Ann_R(s)$. The last equality is precisely the definition.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why $Ann_R(N) = \{ x \in R | sx = 0\}$?

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN We have $N = Ms$. Then $x\in \mathrm{Ann}_r(N)$ iff $0= Nx=Msx$ iff $sx=0$ (because $M$ is faithful).

Comment: Why $N = Ms$ ? we just know the fact that $Ms \subseteq N$.

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN You are right. Nevertheless it does not change the conclusion, because you have $\mathrm{Ann}_R(N) \subseteq \mathrm{Ann}_R(s)$. I will edit my answer to clarify this point and some others that you made.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't know why $Ann_R(N) \subseteq Ann_R(s_0)$, as I know that $s_0$ should be an element in $M$, but in your answer $s_0 \in S$

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN Why $s_0$ should be an element of $M$? I picked $s_0\in S$ such that $Ms_0\subseteq N$ for some finitely generated $R$-module $N$. This is just an application of the definition of $S$-Noetherian.

Comment: by the definition of annihilator of module, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annihilator_(ring_theory).

Comment: @RANGGAJAYACIPTAWAN Since you have got problem with the notation, I will edit my answer once more to make it more accessible.

Comment: Thankyou for your help ^^